# How do I change the permision on a external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, format

Good day,

I am a ubuntu newbie and I am having trouble using an external 3.5" HDD. I did some reading about file systems and decided to format my new drive to ex3. After formatting, I could not read or write because I did not have permission. I have tried pysdm and tried chown but it is still not working. Please could someone provide me with a simple step-by-step "how to" on this?

Thank you,
Andrew

Comment: Can you sucessfully mount that disc? If so, have you tried: sudo chmod -R 777 "directory of hdd", this is only  a test. Having a file with 777 permissions isn't secure. It's only intended to see what may be the problem

Answer (score 1):

If nobody except you is using the drive, you can explicitly mount the drive in your home directory.  I am assuming you are currently simply connecting the drive, and allowing the system to mount it automatically, which it does in the `/media` directory, one which is owned by root.  If it were a permanent directory, then you could change the permissions, but it's dynamic, so you can't.  Therefore, mounting it explicitly in `/etc/fstab` is the best way, I think.

For my instruction, I will assume a directory named "extern"; change this if you wish, but make sure to do so everywhere.  I will also assume your login name is Andrew, just for the example.

Create a directory in your home directory (`/usr/andrew`) named `extern`.

Using the bash terminal, enter a command `sudo blkid`.  Find your external drive in the list, and copy the UUID, hich is in the form of "########-####-####-############".  To copy, highlight with the mouse, and press shift-ctrl-C.

Next, you need to edit a system file using a text editor such as gedit.  To do this, enter the commmand `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`.  At the end of this file add one line like this, substituting the UUID from the clipboard for the "####..." field (**one single line, not two**!):
   `UUID=########-####-####-############ /home/andrew/extern  ext3    rw,suid,dev,exec,noauto,async,nofail,user 0   0`

Save the file, but don't close it yet.

Unmount the external drive using either `sudo umount /dev/sda2`, or whatever number the drive is, or use Nautilus to unmount it.

In the bash terminal, enter the command `sudo mount -a`; this will mount the drives specified in the file.  If there are no errors, check the drive in `~/extern` to see if it is present.  If so, you can close the `/etc/fstab` file.  If there are errors, insert a '#' in the first space of the added line, to disable it, and report back here.

I think you should now be able to use the drive, when it is present.